# Passing characters/strings from R to Fortran

Tags: r, fortran, character

I have a Fortran subroutine  that selects a function based on the value of a string and then executes that function.

```
!! file:select.f90
module funcs
    contains
        subroutine add(x, y, xy)
            real :: x, y, xy
            xy = x + y
            return
        end subroutine

        subroutine diff(x, y, xy)
            real :: x, y, xy
            xy = x - y
            return
        end subroutine
end module

subroutine simple(modname)
    use funcs

    procedure(), pointer :: model => null()

    character(10) :: modname
    real :: x, y, xy

    print *, "-",modname,"-"
    select case (modname)
        case("add")
            model => add
        case("diff")
            model => diff
        case default
            print *, "No model with that name!"
            stop
    end select

    x = 4
    y = 3
    call model(x, y, xy)
    print *, xy

end subroutine
```

I would like to call this subroutine from an R script.

```
# file:select.R
dyn.load("select.so")
.Fortran("simple", "add")
.Fortran("simple", "diff")
```

As a standalone Fortran `program` that takes a command line argument, this runs perfectly fine. It's even insensitive to spaces before or after `modname`. However, when I try to pass in a character as an argument from R, it correctly re-prints the character (without any extra spaces), but then doesn't recognize it as a `case` and skips to the `default`. What is going on here? Is there some encoding issue with R characters that makes them incompatible with Fortran?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Tried, but no luck. It compiles and runs just the same, so there's nothing syntactically wrong with that statement, but it doesn't solve the underlying issue.

EDIT: Original comment was deleted, but the suggestion was to use `select case (adjustl(trim(modname)))`.

Comment: According to this page,  http://www.nag.co.uk/numeric/RunderWindows.asp, "The behaviour of the .Fortran() routine when the Fortran routine it is calling takes character arguments is system specific. It is therefore advisable to avoid using character types by altering the input variable in the wrapper routine". So it might be better to pass integer etc to avoid characters...?

Comment: @roygvib Good find, thank you! I'll keep this question open in case anyone can provide any more insight and/or a workaround, but for the time being, I'll switch to using integer codes.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark: I don't think so.

Comment: If modname can be printed successfully, a potential workaround may be to compare only substring, e.g., if ( modname(1:3) == "add" ) then model => add endif, etc. because this may help avoid potential problems of character encoding (including null termination from the R side).

Comment: Similar to what @roygvib said, I came across this relevant paragraph in "Writing R Extensions".

"Passing character strings to FORTRAN code needs even more care, and should be avoided where possible. Only the first element of the character vector is passed in, as a fixed-length (255) character array. Up to 255 characters are passed back to a length-one character vector. How well this works (or even if it works at all) depends on the C and FORTRAN compilers on each platform (including on their options)."

Answer (score 2):

I believe your select case statement is not properly matching because the `modname` is 10 characters long, and none of your cases cover a string of that length. The best thing to do is to also pass in the length of the string to your Fortran function, then use this to slice your character array.

`subroutine simple(modname,length)`

then `select case (modname(1:length))`

Fortran strings are not zero terminated like the C language. It's an array based language.

Also when passing a string from R to `.Fortran`, it might be better to pass it as raw bytes. Simple example below. First is the Fortran code, then the R wrapper code.

```
subroutine print_this ( str, length )
 integer :: length
 character(length) :: str
 print *, str(1:length)
end subroutine print_this 

test <- function(str) {
  l <- nchar(str) 
  str_raw <- character(l)
  str_raw <- charToRaw(str)
  .Fortran("print_this",str_raw,l)
  l #returns length
}
```

Comment: Note that `case("add")` _will_ match the length-10 character value `"add       "` (that's with seven trailing spaces - not all rendered).  Character values being compared are such that the shorter is treated as being padded with spaces to the length of the longer.